# Imacros unterminated regular expression literal

Tags: javascript, regex, imacros

I want to remove duplicate empty lines in the extracted text

I've tried these:

```
set title eval("var b='{{!extract}}'; var s = b.replace(/\n\s*\n/g, '\n'); s;")

set title eval("var b=\"{{!extract}}\"; var s = b.replace(/\n\s*\n/g, '\n'); s;")
```

but the result is the same:

```
SyntaxError: unterminated regular expression literal, line 10 (Error code: -1001)
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what end result should be, but to fix the error you just need to escape the backslashes.

Since it's being `eval`, you need to basically double-escape all backslashes:

```
eval("var b='{{!extract}}'; var s = b.replace(/\\n\\s*\\n/g, '\\n'); s;")
```